# What is an Independent Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Independent Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Independent Words™ | Not Independent Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| COOLER | HEATER |
| GALAXY | UNIVERSE |
| ILLUSION | PHANTOM |
| ALGEBRA | GEOMETRY |
| OKINAWA | HOKKAIDO |
| NEUTRAL | BIASED |
| VACANT | EMPTY |
| WINDOWS | LINUX |
| SCALLOP | MUSSEL |
| MOBILE | PHONE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Independent Words™,Not Independent Words™
COOLER ,HEATER 
GALAXY ,UNIVERSE 
ILLUSION ,PHANTOM 
ALGEBRA ,GEOMETRY 
OKINAWA ,HOKKAIDO 
NEUTRAL ,BIASED 
VACANT ,EMPTY 
WINDOWS ,LINUX 
SCALLOP ,MUSSEL 
MOBILE ,PHONE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Independent words are ones of which their

> first two letters are US state abbreviations.

They are

> Colorado, Georgia, Illinois, Alabama, Oklahoma, Nebraska, Virginia, Wisconsin, South Carolina and Missouri.
>
>  None of the Not Independent words show this, and the name may refer to the US as an independent country - or that these are individual states.

Comment: Also, Independent is itself an Independent Word™

Comment: Independent is for the rot13(Havgrq Fgngrf Qrpynengvba bs Vaqrcraqrapr) :)

Comment: See also [What is a Unionized Word™?](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51195)