# What is a STATE Word™?

Tags: wordplay, pattern

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a STATE Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\bbox[yellow]{\textbf{STATE Words }^™}&
\bbox[yellow]{\textbf{Not STATE Words }^™}\\ \hline
\text{AKIMBO}&\text{WEAPONS}\\ \hline
\text{CAN}&\text{TIN}\\ \hline
\text{CONTAINER}&\text{RECEPTACLE}\\ \hline
\text{FLAGON}&\text{VESSEL}\\ \hline
\text{MEETING}&\text{ASSEMBLY}\\ \hline
\text{OHMAGE}&\text{ELECTRICITY}\\ \hline
\text{SCHOLARSHIP}&\text{EDUCATION}\\ \hline
\text{VACATION}&\text{HOLIDAY}\\ \hline
\text{WITHDRAW}&\text{RETREAT}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

These are just some examples of STATE Words there are many more.

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
STATE Words™, Not STATE Words™
AKIMBO, WEAPONS
CAN, TIN
CONTAINER, RECEPTACLE 
FLAGON, VESSEL
MEETING, ASSEMBLY
OHMAGE, ELECTRICITY
SCHOLARSHIP, EDUCATION
VACATION, HOLIDAY
WITHDRAW, RETREAT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an Independent Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/what-is-an-independent-word), I'm glad we have the same thoughts :P

Comment: @Conifers THAT was the one I was looking for - knew I'd seen it somewhere! Karm: yes, there are an awful lot of this type of puzzle on the site now, so spotting one that's already been done can be quite the challenge (as I just demonstrated myself!).

Comment: How can we check if a question has been asked before? Is there a page that collates questions from "What is a *** Word?" series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A STATE word is

> a word where the first two letters are also a US State Abbreviation

> **AK**IMBO, Alaska
>  **CA**N, California
>  **CO**NTAINER, Colorado
>  **FL**AGON, Florida
>  **ME**ETING, Maine
>  **OH**MAGE, Ohio
>  **SC**HOLARSHIP, South Carolina
>  **VA**CATION, Virginia
>  **WI**THDRAW, Wisconsin

Comment: Well that was fast, really fast. Well done. Was the title a bit too much of a give away?

Comment: I was so afraid of being sniped I was probably doing twice my normal typing speed :P Yeah, the title was probably too much (and I'm not even from the US).